# array subscript operator in for loop counter

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, for-loop

I am learning C. In the following code why does replacing "*ptr_str" with "ptr_str[i]" in the for loop truncate?

```
/* 13L01.c: Initializing strings */
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
 char str1[] = {'A', ' ',
 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ',
 'c', 'o', 'n', 's', 't', 'a', 'n', 't', '\0'};
  char str2[] = "Another string constant";
  char *ptr_str;
  int i;

  /* print out str2 */
  for (i=0; str1[i]; i++)
      printf("%c", str1[i]);
      printf("\n");
  /* print out str2 */
  for (i=0; str2[i]; i++)
      printf("%c", str2[i]);
      printf("\n");
   /* assign a string to a pointer */
   ptr_str = "Assign a strings to a pointer.";
   for (i=0; *ptr_str; i++)
       printf("%c", *ptr_str++);
   return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Because you're advancing `ptr_str` and then treating it as an array and testing if it's pointing to `NULL` on the i'th member. You're basically testing if `ptr_str[i+i]` is `NULL` instead of `ptr_str[i]`.

Comment: ASCII NUL (`'\0'`) is not NULL (`(void *)0`).

Comment: @Chris: `NULL` is not necessarily `(void*)0` it may be `0` or `0L` or equivalent even in plain C.

Comment: @Jens - I know, but @kichik wants the NUL character, which is `'\0'`. Even if using `NULL` might compile and work, it's still important to differentiate the two (especially to beginners).

Comment: @Chris: Sure. Just wanted to state the "real" value of `NULL`, namely that there isn't :) at least nothing reliable.

Answer (score 2):

```
   // A, ok
   while (*ptr_str)
       printf("%c", *ptr_str++);

   // B, also ok
   for (i=0; ptr_str[i]; i++)
       printf("%c", ptr_str[i]);

   // C, works but ugly
   for (i=0; *ptr_str; i++)
       printf("%c", *ptr_str++);
```

C is your form, it is flawed because i is doing nothing here, so A is an improved version. If you want to use i, do it like B. If you use both i and ptr_str, and increment both of them in the loop, nothing good will happen. Increment one or the other.

Comment: I answered, then reread your answer and figured out that you had already answered it, just with fewer words. So +1

Comment: @gmiket Truncation is absolutely not a necessary consequence of prt_str[i] as the test in the for loop. See my B) snippet, which works fine.

Comment: @Chris, thanks your answer is good too, so +1 for you from me too!

Comment: // C, works but ugly
   for (i=0; *ptr_str; i++)
       printf("%c", *ptr_str++;);
seems to me a pointless construction. Why not just  for (; *ptr_str;)
       printf("%c", *ptr_str++);

Comment: @gmiket I agree it's a pointless contruction, I only mentioned it because that is the code you posted !!!! Your suggestion of
for (; *ptr_str;) printf("%c", *ptr_str++); is just a slightly uglier version of my while (*ptr_str) printf("%c", *ptr_str++); Both are fine and will work.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear, but I think I've got it:

> In the following code why does replacing "*ptr_str" with "ptr_str[i]" in the for loop truncate?

I think you mean changing this:

```
for (i=0; *ptr_str; i++)
    printf("%c", *ptr_str++);
return 0;
```

to this:

```
for (i=0; ptr_str[i]; i++)
    printf("%c", *ptr_str++);
return 0;
```

The second one truncates because you're advancing `i` *and* `ptr_str`, so the modified starting position of `ptr_str` *plus* the modified starting position of `i` ends up cutting you off too soon (or worse, having an odd number of characters and overflowing into data that isn't yours). The second example that truncates is equivalent to:

```
for (i=0; ptr_str[i * 2]; i++)
    printf("%c", ptr_str[i]);
return 0;
```

Now do you see why it truncates?